# How to map between simple object to protobuff object in java using Object Mapper

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, objectmapper

I want to map between simple object to protobuff using object mapper
when i tried this it cause an exception

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
return objectMapper.convertValue(enterprise, EnterpriseMessage.Enterprise.class);
```

Exception message was: cannot find a (map) key deserializer for type simple type

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion `objectmapper` is not the best option to map protos
since `objectmapper` is used to map `JSON` into `POJO's` and vice versa.

My recomendation for this purpose is using `mapstruct` which provides
a wide functionality to map `java beans`. Specially between `protos` and `POJO's`.

Just by creating an `interface` mapper for the `class` you want to map the framework
generates the implementacion.

I write you an example that you can follow.

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface EnterpriseProtoMapper {
  EnterpriseMessage.Enterprise toProto(Enterprise enterprise);
}
```

For further information, you can check `mapStruct`'s documentation in this link:

[MapStruct 1.3.1.Final Reference Guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.3/reference/html/)

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk for some reason, after i integrate github.com/entur/mapstruct-spi-protobuf get an error saying error: Couldn't retrieve Mapper annotation